# tracking bugs in release like debug mode

Tags: android, flutter

with debug mode the app works good but after --release build the app work on phone but hanging on signin I want to tracking the issue like in debug mode , is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what your issue is? Not just debugging in release mode, but what exactly is your issue. It could the case that your release config is missing Internet permissions, if it's an Android app.

Comment: I send issue to database to read it it's was about com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 10:

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: no problem I have stored the issue that happened in database to be able to know it , the error is "com.google.android.gms.common.api.b:" when I use google_signin

Comment: That doesn't look like an error though. That looks like a Library reference.

Comment: yes it'a about production keyStore fingerprint hash but I seeking about if there way to debugging production release and tracking issue or there isn't

Answer (score 0):

There's a section on flutter docs that helps you create bug reports using sentry.

[Here it is](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting)